# Divergence of the series of the inverses of the prime numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, divergent-series

Can you help me prove that the $\sum \limits _{p \text{ prime}} \dfrac 1 p$ is divergent?

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: The fact about the series is in Hardy and Wright, I believe due to Mertens. You can look it up as easily as we. Unlikely there is any truly easy derivation

Comment: HW theorem 427 in the fifth edition.  They say Euler proved series divergence in 1737

Comment: If $\sum\limits_{n\,\in\,A} \dfrac 1 n$ converges, then so does $\sum\limits_{n\,\in\,B} \dfrac 1 n$, where $B$ is the closure of $A$ under multiplication.  The closure under multiplication of the set of all prime numbers is all of $\mathbb N$.  So the proof of the first assertion I made in this comment is what needs to be done. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a proof. Of course, the hard part lies in the results that are used for this sketch.

A consequence of the *Prime Number theorem* is the $n$th prime number function $p_n$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\;n\log n$ (actually, it is equivalent to the Prime Number theorem).

Hence $\dfrac1{p_n}\sim \dfrac1{n\log n}$, so that the series $\displaystyle\sum_n\frac1{p_n}\enspace\text{and}\enspace\sum_n\frac1{n\log n}$ both converge or both diverge. However, the latter is a Bertrand's series which diverge.